# Find first empty cell in column range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a loop to find the first empty cell in Column D of highlighted range (See picture) and return the row value (integer). However, I'm struggling to find a solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script finds the last used row in a specified column and returns the next available row.

```
/* 
* Credit: Jean-Pierre Verhulst 
* https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aSdhRaEhMeM
*/

function getLastUsedRow(sheet, colNum) {
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, colNum, 
  sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(),
  l = values.length,
  row;
  while (l > 0) {
    if (values[l] && values[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
      row = (l + 2);
      break;
    } else {
      l--;
    }
  }
  return  row || 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Probably a bad habit/workaround. But works nonetheless.

```js
function getFirstEmptyRowV2() {
  var row;
  var Archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Staff_Archive');
        values = Archive.getRange("D6:D")
            .getValues(),
        row = 0; 
    for (row; row < values.length; row++) {
        if (!values[row].join("")) break;
    }
    return row + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this get a column height.  So just add one to it.

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```